# Getting the name of clicked button

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my webpage, there are afew href buttons created dynamically.

For example, there will be four href buttons created and user might have clicked on two of the href buttons.

1) Whenever a href button is clicked, the text of the href button will be changed from "select" to "selected".

2) Once the user finished clicking on two of the href buttons, the user will click on the "NEXT" button.

When the user click on thr NEXT button I am trying to get the name of those href button showing the text "Selected". How can I go about getting it done?

The code for creating href buttons:

```
<?php
     while($rowModelList=mysql_fetch_array($resultModelList))
     {
?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
    <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="Images/Models/<? echo $rowModelList['modelImage'];?>" alt="" style="height: 200px;">
         <div class="caption">
              <h4><?php echo $rowModelList['modelName']?></h4>
              <p>
              <a href="#" id="<?php echo $rowModelList['Id']?>" onClick="return changecolor(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
              </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

The code for creating NEXT button:

```
<div class="row text-right">
     <a href="#" id="nextbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>
</div>
```

The code to change the href button text from "select" to "selected" upon clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* Changing the colour of the button upon clicked */
        function changecolor(element) {

            if(element.innerHTML == "Select") {
                        element.innerHTML = "Selected";
                        element.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0"; /* Grey became seleted */
                        element.style.borderColor = "#C0C0C0";

                  }

            else {
                element.innerHTML = "Select";
                element.style.backgroundColor = "#FED136"; /* Yellow not selected */
                element.style.borderColor = "#FED136";            }
            return false;
        }
     </script>
```

Comment: Can u show it on fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

While changing the text from "Select" to "Selected", add a class to the selected button (and remove it from the other) to find it more easily later.
Something like this:

```
    <div class="caption">
        <a href="#" id="first" onClick="changecolor(this)" class="select-btn btn btn-primary">Select</a>
        <a href="#" id="second" onClick="changecolor(this)" class="select-btn btn btn-primary">Select</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-right">
        <a href="#" id="nextbtn" onClick="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>
    </div>


    <script>
        function changecolor(element) {
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("select-btn");
            for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
                buttons[i].classList.remove('selected-btn');
                buttons[i].innerHTML = "Select";
            }

            if(!element.classList.contains('selected-btn') ){
                element.innerHTML = "Selected";
                element.classList.add('selected-btn');
            }
        }

        function next(){
            alert( document.getElementsByClassName("selected-btn")[0].getAttribute('id') );
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try if you're using jQuery

```
var hrefButton = "";
jQuery('#nextbtn').on('click',function(){       
    hrefButton = jQuery('#nextbtn').attr('href');
    console.log(hrefButton);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the anchor tags with the text selected as:

```
$('#nextbtn').click(function(){

   var searchText = "Selected";
   var searchEles = document.getElementById("caption").children;
   for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {
     if (searchEles[i].textContent == searchText) {
     console.log(searchEles[i]);   
   }
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code.
It is working correctly as per your need i think.

```
$('#mybutton').on('click',function(){
    var i=0;
    $("a").each(function(){
        if($(this).html()=="selected")
        {
            // do what you want
            i++;
        }
    });
    alert(i);
})
```

Here in above code i used "i" variable which i used only to count number of anchors which contains selected text you can remove it and manipulate code as per your need. please check it once.

I have also created small example please check following link.

[Example Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jLLj5jLd/)

Answer (score -1):

here's an example for you.. it's jquery.

```
<a href = "#" id="linkHere">Select</a>


$('.linkHere').click(function(){

  $(this).text("Selected");

});
```